# what is the difference between Android-Universal-Image-Loader and ImageLoader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

(https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader)
VS
(https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) 
I just want to know the differences between Android-Universal-Image-Loader and ImageLoader.
Which is better? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well both are image caching library used for lazy loading images (a process where images are loaded at last just like in a webpage) and other stuffs I used universal image loader and found it to be fantastic. I have not used the other library yet but looking at the github repo it looks promising and offers similar features. The only way to know which is better is by trying it yourself. If you do please let us know.

Comment: thanks,I should study more about java language!!!

Comment: @user3764964 yap you should definately make yourself comfortable with java first